# Trouble with array and curve modifiers for making a bandolier - Blender

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

First ever question, I'm also not amazing at blender and trying to learn.
I want to make a bandolier for the sake of learning a more complex array modifier (and curves) but I am having trouble getting the bullets to rotate along the curve or to get the curve lines to face the way I want.

I've tried looking up videos that suggest shrinkwrapping the curve to the object (as well as using triangles parented to the bullets that are also shrinkwrapped) but nothing seems to work so far.

If anyone can help me out of this I'd appreciate it greatly!

[image: Bandolier with bullets1]

[[image: Bandolier with bullets2][2]]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: This may help you : selecting a vertex in a curve and then pressing `CTRL+T` will allow you to tilt the vertex's normal to a direction you want. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: Mqbaka solved it, thanks a lot!